# Adjusting a sliding patio door: does the door have to rest equally on both rollers?

Tags: patio, door-frame

I have a strange problem. Both jambs are plumb, the sill is level but the sliding door does not close properly if I do not raise one of the rollers almost to the maximum. Funny thing is that this misalignment happens when the moving door is also set plumb. Geometrically this should not be possible.

[image]

One of the issues I am trying to solve is to keep the edges of the two doors, the fixed one and the sliding one when closed perfectly overlapped so achieve perfect insulation

Comment: Have you checked your level by swapping ends and reading the bubble again?

Comment: yes I did, it reads OK

Comment: Your concern about load would be valid if something was holding the door such that one wheel is lifted. That's not the case with a typical patio door. As John Canon stated, something else is going on that requires such an odd configuration. Check plumb on the door in various positions to detect curvature in the track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving a roller up or down has a minuscule effect on the load shared by the two wheels. The door's center of gravity will not move more than one-half inch either way. The two wheels will always share the load equally +/- 5%. Wheel replacements are available, or remove the door and oil the pivot points.

The top or bottom sill can have a dip or a bulge and still read level. Use a string line to check your bottom sill. From your drawing, a dip in the middle of the bottom plate would cause the 2 glass sections to lean toward each other. Set the rollers to achieve parallel between each section, and between the sliding glass and the side frame. If you lower the sliding part, be sure the frame remains in the top track.

Comment: my question is will it damage the track if the load on rollers in not equally split between the two rollers? By raising one you get the vertical edges of the sliding door to be parallel with the verticals of the frame but the load on the rollers is not equal and it my wear down the track

Comment: Moving a roller up or down has a miniscule effect on the load shared by the 2 wheels. The door's center of gravity will not move more than one-half inch either way. The 2 wheels will always share 50-50 plus or minus 5 percent. Wheel replacements are available, or remove the door and oil the pivot points.