# Is there an objective way to measure how easily a sliding patio door is moving and if it is adjusted properly?

Tags: doors, patio

Is there an objective way to measure how easy a sliding patio door is moving and if it is adjusted properly?

I just installed my sliding vinyl patio door and since it is slightly larger than usual (not a standard size by some companies) I am not sure if it should move easier or not

This is not the same as the question I asked previously about unequally adjusting the door rollers

Comment: Using a simple pull force meter will tell you "how easily" it moves, but what would you then compare that to?  Should it move with 2 lbs of force or is 10 lbs normal?  Can the manufacturer provide any details?

Comment: I would imagine that the door came with installation instructions. Check those for testing the door's operability. Basically the door should slide just as easily forwards as it does backwards. The lock should latch with minimal effort. You should not experience abrupt difficulty when sliding the door. The door should not open nor close on its own. Place a level on it to make sure it's not leaning into nor out of your home. Measure diagonally from upper left to bottom right and upper right to bottom left to make sure the door is square otherwise you'll encounter difficulty sliding the door.

Comment: Believe it or not, any reputable manufacturer wants you to be successful when installing or using their product so they will cram as much information into their manual as possible. It's up to you to read it and understand the information. If their manual doesn't have much detail then call the company and ask for assistance or seek out competitor manuals of a similar product. I cannot stress this enough. I read through the entire manual of all products I buy which can be considered to have a difficulty rating greater than 1 out of 5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjusting a sliding patio door: does the door have to rest equally on both rollers?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/177744/adjusting-a-sliding-patio-door-does-the-door-have-to-rest-equally-on-both-rolle)

Comment: I don't think my manufacturer wants that https://www.farleywindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Patio-Door-Guide.pdf

Comment: @JPhi1618 yeah I guess that could be a scientific way to do it

Comment: I just used a $15 strap luggage scale to test my old aluminum doors, 1.5 lbs. If you have significant weatherstripping, yours could be closer to 5 lbs.

Comment: yes I think if the door is new that adds to the issue. I was afraid that the frame could be warped. I noticed that if I push upward the top of the frame the door moves kind of easier frame is not screwed yet
There is a lot of false assumptions based on basic geometry and but many forget (I just learned this the hard way) that there is a lot of play room between the top of the frame and doors AND between the doors and the inner vertical sides of the frame. The weatherstrip is what closed those spaces and you don't realize that being perfectly square and plumb is not mandatory but good to have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erpUegt5pqo
and then go to Home Depot or Lowes and pull their doors on the display
Please vote if you agree with this method so I can selected as the answer or come up with a better way

Also some references
https://idighardware.com/2009/02/door-opening-force/
https://adata.org/factsheet/adjusting-doors-access

and the code says:
https://www.thebuildingcodeforum.com/forum/threads/opening-force-for-sliding-doors.7752/

```
2. Sliding or folding doors: 5 pounds (22.2 N) maximum.
```

These forces do not apply to the force required to retract latch bolts or disengage other devices that

hold the door or gate in a closed position.

Advisory 404.2.9 Door and Gate Opening Force. The maximum force pertains to the

continuous application of force necessary to fully open a door, not the initial force needed to

overcome the inertia of the door. It does not apply to the force required to retract bolts or to

disengage other devices used to keep the door in a closed position.